# Trying to change value in one column based on the value of another column in same row

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 6 worksheets in an excel workbook that each have about 20,000 rows.  In the example I've provided below, I'm trying to change the value of "Grade Subtotal" to an empty string value in the D column if the value in the C column of that row has a value of "Location Subtotal".

I've tried using the VLOOKUP function but to no avail.  I don't work with Excel much and hope someone might be able to shed some light on my issue.

Any suggestions/direction on how to accomplish that would be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is my PIC:

[image: Excel worksheet]

Comment: Could you do something like this: `=IF(AND(C3="Location Subtotal",D3="Grade Subtotal"),"", D3)`  That is if your C column has Location Subtotal AND your D column has Grade Subtotal replace with an empty string else keep d3.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply JonH.  I'll give it a try as that is exactly what I'm needing.  One question.  Will that take care of finding all the Location Subtotal values in the C column?

Comment: Hey JonH, unfortunately that didn't work.  I got a circular references... error returned.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start for a single sheet:

```
Sub Melinda()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        If Cells(i, "C").Value = "Location Subtotal" Then
            If Cells(i, "D").Value = "Grade Subtotal" Then
                Cells(i, "D").Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, I'll give it a try.  Appreciate the reply.

Comment: Gary, that got it!!  Thank you so much for your help and time.